# Differentiate between fileRejections and isDragReject in useDropzone hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using fileRejections for catching files which have size larger than 5MB and isDragReject for files which are not csv like this:-

```
const maxSize=5242880;
const CSVDropzone = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();


  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, fileRejections, isDragActive, isDragAccept, isDragReject } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: 'text/csv',
    minSize: 0,
    maxSize,
  });
  let isFileTooLarge = fileRejections.length > 0 && fileRejections[0].errors.length;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Grid container {...getRootProps()} className={classes.dropzone}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {isDragActive ? (
          <p>Drop here ...</p>
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
            <BackupOutlinedIcon />
            <p>Drag and drop or click to browse</p>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </Grid>
      <Grid container>      
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            {isFileTooLarge && (
            <Typography variant="caption">File is too large. Allowed maximum sixe is 5 Mb.</Typography>
            )}
            {isDragReject && (
            <Typography variant="caption">Incorrect file format. Please upload a CSV file. </Typography>
            )}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

**PROBLEM:** when a non-csv file is dragged..Till the time that drag is happening, we'll see `Incorrect file format`The moment the file is dropped, we see `File is too large`

 I feel that since isDragReject is internal to useDropzone, it is only true till the drop is in progress. I want it to stay true until the next onDrop.
Can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, a state variable can help you here.

> I want it to stay true until the next onDrop.
> Can someone suggest something?

To achieve this, we will update its value only when `isDragActive` is true.

For example, you can declare a state variable like,

```
const [isRejected, setIsRejected] = useState(false);
```

and before the return statement, the following condition can be added,

```
if (isDragActive && isRejected != isDragReject) {
    setIsRejected(isDragReject);
}
```

After this, you can use `isRejected` instead of `isDragReject` for your rendering.

**PS:** I'm still a beginner in React, so please correct me if I am making any wrong assumptions here.

Comment: Actually, isDragReject will change the moment the file dragged thingy has completed.. so after a few seconds it will become false itself -> making isRejected false too. So, this approach will not work

Comment: did you try this? Because as soon as "file dragged thingy" is completed, `isDragActive` will also become false. I tried with a simple example on codesandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-diffie-zgv62e?file=/src/App.js